# Substituting lone characters or chars separated by comma

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have the following data and am looking to substitute only single characters.

```
A,Apple
A
```

I want to produce the output such that

```
Banana,Apple
Banana
```

In other words I want to substitute anything that has an A, or just an A with banana. But if another word starting with A comes in, I want to ignore that.

I tried

```
gsub("A", "Banana"),
gsub("A[^,;]","Banana"),
```

But this wont work for the first example, the output I get is

```
Banana,Bpple
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Comment: You need a quantifier. The pattern `"A.*"` will match an `A` followed by 0 or more characters of any type. If you want to put restrictions, just replace `.` with `[^,;]` or somthing

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your question. Can you make a reproducible example that makes clear what your desired output is?

Comment: `sub("^A($|,)", "Apple\\1", x)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value is always surrounded by punctuation or line start/end:

```
text = "A,Apple\nA\nAvocado"
text2 = gsub("(\\b)A(\\b)", "\\1Bananna\\2", text, TRUE, TRUE)
cat(text2)
```

This captures the punctuation, if any exist, around the "A", and then puts them back using the backreferences `\1` and `\2`. PCRE are used so we can use the `\b` word boundary match.

Output:

```
Bananna,Apple
Bananna
Avocado
```

Comment: Thanks all for the wealth of approaches!

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution could be to split the string on comma (`,`), change the value to "Banana" if it is equal to "A"

```
sapply(strsplit(x, ","), function(x) toString(ifelse(x == "A","banana", x)))
#[1] "banana, Apple" "banana"
```

**data**

```
x <- c("A,Apple", "A")
```